# DDX_Text parses wrong value when at least one Edit field has a decimal value

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on an MFC application. I have a CFormView with a few Edit Control boxes. I'm directly mapping their values to variables inside an object of class `Setpoint`.

```
typedef struct {
    float fAmplitud;
    float fFase;
} fasor;

class Setpoint {
    public:
        Setpoint() {
          oV1 = oV2 = oV3 = { 0 };  
        }
    public:
        fasor oV1;
        fasor oV2;
        fasor oV3;
};
```

To read their values I use `UpdateData(TRUE)`. `DoDataExchange` looks like this:

```
void View_Control::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){
  CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_oSetpoint.oV1.fAmplitud);
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT3, m_oSetpoint.oV2.fAmplitud);
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT5, m_oSetpoint.oV3.fAmplitud);
};
```

Something happens which looks like a bug, and it's this: as long as all user input remains integer, everything works fine.

If at least one number has a decimal part, say `IDC_EDIT1` is 1.5, then every other box that has a decimal part too, works fine (even if it's 1.00). Every box that doesn't have a decimal part, gets parsed wrong.

For example, if I input: 10 in `IDC_EDIT1`, 1 in `IDC_EDIT3` and 0 in `IDC_EDIT5`, I get the values `10.00`, `1.00`, `0.00`

On the other hand, if I input: 10.1 in `IDC_EDIT1`, 0 in `IDC_EDIT3` and 0 in `IDC_EDIT5`, I get the values `10.10`, `0.10`, `0.10`

What's going on?

UPDATE:
There seems to be a problem with `_sntscanf_s` inside `DDX_Text`: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1793346/major-defect-in-a-very-basic-mfc-dialog-containing-numerical-double-floating-point-input-fields-only-happens-in-x64-release). One workaround is to edit the source code and replace `_sntscanf_s` with `sscanf_s`, but for some reason I can't see the source code in VS2015.

Comment: Can't you debug this ? MFC sourc code is provided and it's easy to step into MFC code. Just put a breakpoint on the corresponding `DDX_Text(pDX,...` in your  `View_Control::DoDataExchange` method.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, I can't step into it. It steps over `DDX_Text`, and right click, go to definition/declaration just takes me to this line `void AFXAPI DDX_Text(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, float& value);` in afxdd_.h

Comment: Did you try what I've suggested in my 1st comment.  Put a breakpoint on the corresponding `DDX_Text(pDX,...` in your `View_Control::DoDataExchange` method, run the program and as soon as it hits the breakpoint step into the MFC code by pressing the `F11` key (or menu Debug->Step into) and see what's going on. It works here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, yes that's what I've tried, it steps over anyway. It seems to be a problem with `_sntscanf_s` inside `DDX_Text` [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1793346/major-defect-in-a-very-basic-mfc-dialog-containing-numerical-double-floating-point-input-fields-only-happens-in-x64-release) . Which sucks, because if I could see the source code maybe I could fix it, like suggested in that link. 

I'm trying the other workaround, installing SDK 10, but I can't get it to install due to some weird installation error...

Comment: Changing MFC source code is not a solution, regardless what the problem is.